# Zend Framework additional Get params with NGINX

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx, get

I configured my NGINX for Zend in the following way (PHP 5.3 with fpm):

```
server {
root /home/page/public/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Now i want to process additional get params like: http://web.site/index?par=1

WIth my local dev system (Apache) it works fine but not under NGINX which did'T deliver the get params.

Anny suggestions?

Edit:

Now i use the following config which seems to work but i'm not happy with it since everybody suggests "use try_files whenever possible".

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite  /(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How actually do you try to get it?

Comment: To test  it with print_r($_GET) but later with $values = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();

Comment: The Problem isn't the script the problem is think is that the script filename is index.php without the params, so php cant fill the $_GET array etc.

Comment: Try this `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` instead of `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Nginx docs ( http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files):

> If you need args preserved, you must do so explicitly:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use a [rewrite module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) for this; try replacing your `location /` block with the following:

```
location / { 
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}   

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works i already tried it and was about to edit my question but everybody says "use try_files whenever possible" so i'm still interested in a solution for it.