# Zend getParams not returing url params

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I have a query: 
https://myaddress.ee/admin/usersearchajax?country=EE&query=arno

$this->_request->getParam('query');
returns: NULL

var_dump($_REQUEST['query']);
returns: string(5) "arno"

How to fix this problem? I mean how to get GET values with zend framework?
Lets assume i can't change the query string.

zend version 1.11.11

```
    public function usersearchajaxAction(){
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender( true );

    $userService = new Application_Services_User();

    $userList = $userService->searchByName($this->_request->getParam('query'));
    $this->_helper->json($userService->getArrayForAutoComplete($this->_request->getParam('query'), $userList));

}
```

I found the problem, there was and override of $_GET variable in my project.
So it is fix now. thank you all for reading and thinking about this

Comment: I had the same problem. Caused by a bad nginx configuration, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7353934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
$this->_request->getParam('query');
```

use this

```
$this->_getParam('query');
```

there is no need to use request action helper in Action to get this params

or try to use this way which uses request action helper

```
$request  = $this->getRequest();
$query = $request->getParam('query');
```

hope this [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.accessors) will help you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `$this->_request->getParam()`. The second form you mention is syntactic sugar that proxies to the first form. SImilarly, behind the scenes, getting a reference to the request action helper and calling the `getParam` method is exactly the same as `$this->_request->getParam()`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can view all params in a row `$this->_request->getParams();`
Then find needle param in a row and get using `$this->_request->getParam('needle');`

Comment: `getAllParams` method should be `getParams`. I can't edit to change because edits need to be more than 6 chars.